# Error in custom PipeLine class with Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, puppeteer, pipeline, typescript-generics

I am creating a web scrapping application with Puppeteer where I want to create a PipeLine class that takes takes the current instance of page and exposes an add method that takes array of functions with type `PipeLineFn`, innvoke them which returns a promise as a result after doing there task and pass that as an argu to the next function which will be treated as an output of the previous one in the line and so on.

Then the add returns a promise for which I will await which marks the completion of all the tasks in that array.

I tried to do the implementation for the same:

```
type PipeLineFn = <T>(arg: Page, output?: Promise<T>) => Promise<T>;
type ReturnFnType<T> = T extends <R>(
  arg: Page,
  output?: Promise<R>
) => Promise<R>
  ? R
  : any;

export class PipeLine {
  output?: Promise<ReturnFnType<PipeLineFn>>;

  constructor(private page: Page) {}

  public add(args: (PipeLineFn | undefined)[]) {
    const toBeDone = args.map(fn => {
      if(fn === undefined) return undefined;
      this.output = this.__add__(fn, this.page, this.output);
      return this.output;
    });

    return Promise.all(toBeDone);
  }

  private __add__ = <T>(fn: PipeLineFn, page: Page, output?: Promise<T>) =>
    fn(page, output);
}



// consuming add();

 const pipe = new PipeLine(page);   // page comes from Puppeteer
 await pipe.add([setAllCookies, openLoginPage]);
```

**Expected result :**
I want that the add() should do all these tasks in the same order and also provide output from the prev func which is a promise to the next one which can consume it based on the situation.

**Errors :**
But I am getting errors like **Cannot find name 'R'** in ReturnFnType which I dont understant why is that case.

I am stuck here so please correct me where am I going wrong with the implementation and what I should do please provide your suggession.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use `R` as a result of the conditional type, you have to `infer` it:

```
type Page = any;

type PipeLineFn = <T>(arg: Page, output?: Promise<T>) => Promise<T>;
type ReturnFnType<T> = T extends <R>(
  arg: Page,
  output?: Promise<infer R>
) => Promise<infer R>
  ? R
  : any;

type x = ReturnFnType<(arg: Page, output?: Promise<string>)=>Promise<string>>;
//   ^? type x = string
```